# How to change visual studio text editor to default?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, text-editor

I broke text editor visual of visual studio.it is funny but i couldn't restore it.Could you please help me to restore back?

You can show the pictures to understand the problem

**Original**

[image]

**Disrupted**
[image]

**the original one shows pop-up window like this;**
[image]

Comment: What are you complaining about?  Is this about the font, the size of the text or the popup window?

Comment: not size of the text, the problem is dissapering of the pop-up and color of identifier

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: yes I am using ReSharper, I am working on two VS instance, one of them is problematic.

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2015:

Option 1

1. Tools >
2. Fonts and Colors >
3. Select "Use Defaults" on the top right corner
4. press "OK"

Option 2

1. Open Visual Studio and Go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings
2. Select Reset all Settings and complete the wizard
3. Restart VS instance

Comment: I think there is another problem.Because when I come on class identifier, ı am waiting to see pop-up window that show some information about the identifier.Disrupted one show any pop-up window but original one show pop-up window. You can see the difference the pictures that I will upload now

Comment: Try to do the 2nd option in Vivek answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4855206-06e4-4fb6-925f-0ab828555240/tooltip-missing-on-member-name-in-vsiaul-studio-2012?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Before I asked the question, ı am tried the option.But I didi't solve it